# OnChange event on select list with jQuery does not working

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

I have a jQuery function that does as follows: on changing a select list value it displays a div.
Code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function) {
  $('#listPaymentOptimum').on('change', function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    switch (currentValue) {
      case '1':
        alert(this.value); // or $(this).val()
        $("#payOptimumFortumo").show();
        $("#payOptimumStripe").hide();
        $("#payOptimumPaypal").hide();

        break;
      case '2':
        $("#payOptimumFortumo").hide();
        $("#payOptimumStripe").show();
        $("#payOptimumPaypal").hide();

        break;
      case '3':
        $("#payOptimumFortumo").hide();
        $("#payOptimumStripe").hide();
        $("#payOptimumPaypal").show();

        break;
      default:
        $("#payOptimumFortumo").hide();
        $("#payOptimumStripe").hide();
        $("#payOptimumPaypal").show();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="listPaymentCorporate">
  <option value="">Please select your payment mode</option>
  <option value="1">Stripe</option>
  <option value="2">Paypal</option>
  <option value="3">Cryptodevises</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="payOptimumFortumo">Fortumo here
</div>
<div id="payOptimumStripe">Stripe here
</div>
<div id="payOptimumPaypal">Paypal here
</div>
```

When I select something in the select list, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for your help. It is very much appreciated :)

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. I'd say this is off-topic question. Please open the debug console of your browser and check the error messages there. And this $('#listPaymentOptimum') has not the same ID as the HTML select.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` of the select list `listPaymentCorporate` isn't the same as the element that the change event attached to `listPaymentOptimum`.

**NOTE1:** The ready function has a missing open-parenthesis in :

```
$(document).ready(function){
__________________________^
```

**NOTE2:** You could hide multiple elements at the same statement using the comma `,` separator in the selector like :

```
$("#payOptimumFortumo, #payOptimumPaypal").hide();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#listPaymentCorporate').on('change', function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();

    switch (currentValue) {
      case '1':
        $("#payOptimumStripe").show();
        $("#payOptimumFortumo, #payOptimumPaypal").hide();

        break;
      case '2':
        $("#payOptimumPaypal").show();
        $("#payOptimumFortumo, #payOptimumStripe").hide();

        break;
      case '3':
        $("#payOptimumFortumo").show();
        $("#payOptimumPaypal, #payOptimumStripe").hide();

        break;
      default:
        $("#payOptimumPaypal").show();
        $("#payOptimumFortumo, #payOptimumStripe").hide();

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="listPaymentCorporate">
  <option value="">Please select your payment mode</option>
  <option value="1">Stripe</option>
  <option value="2">Paypal</option>
  <option value="3">Cryptodevises</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="payOptimumFortumo">Fortumo here</div>
<div id="payOptimumStripe">Stripe here</div>
<div id="payOptimumPaypal">Paypal here</div>
```